# Help with transformation of Drawed Layout to MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I’m making a sample application that uses MigLayout in a very cool way. Unfortunately after reading through the quickstart and the whitepaper I still have questions and can’t do my desired layout. The sample application lets you add/remove games which are basically an Info Panel + JLabel. The layout should have two rows, one for the info panel and the other one to the JLabel.

Layout:

- Row 1 (Info Panel) : [grow][grow][grow][grow]
- Row 2 (JLabels) :   [grow][grow][grow][grow][/list]

Here is an image so you guys can see clearly:
[image]

So when I add a Game the layout should shrink the other to fit, like on this image:
[image]

And when I delete the layout should grow the remaining one:
[image]

But it’s not working with the given layout info, can you guys give me a hand? Also the shrinking JLabel should be handed by me, since it can’t resize automatically???

Comment: *"I’m making a sample application that uses MigLayout in a very cool way."*  Since when does 'broken' equate to 'cool'?  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a simple GridLayout will do the trick.

Yes, you will need to do custom paint to resize the image as the space available to it changes. This means you will probably need to use a JPanel and draw the image manually so you can scale the image on the fly.

Comment: going to take a look at that :)